# unable to install grub in /dev/sda

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation

I've already installed Ubuntu 16.04 in the D drive of my laptop a few days ago, and I uninstalled it yesterday.
(I deleted all things in my D drive partitions and merged(?) them.)

Then I got some message about grub as below:

```
GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta 2-36 ubuntu 3.7
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.
For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions.
Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.
grub>
```

So I did something I found from a google search and I can boot with Windows now.

However, **when I try to reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 in my D drive, "I can't install grub in /dev/sda" so I can't boot with Ubuntu too.**

Is there anyone who know why this error message occurs?
Did I do something wrong while I booted laptop with windows?

Sorry for my terrible English.
Thank you
Park

Comment: Some research suggests this is an issue caused by secure boot. You might disable it in the BIOS and try installing again.

Comment: Also if you google the error message you can probably find something useful.